# Laravel9 N+1 issue showing job title a task belongs to

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I'm trying to get the title of a job belonging to a task. When i try to get the title I get a N+1 popup from my laravel debugbar. This instructs me to use with but whichever way I have tried (using with('App/Models/Job') or just with('job') or setting protected $with = ['job'] etc) I still get the N+1 popup.
So heres the applicable code
App/Models/Job.php

```
public function tasks()
    {
        return $this->hasMany( Task::class);
    }
```

App/Models/Task.php

```
    public function job()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo( Job::class);
    }
```

App/Models/Planner.php

```
public static function getTask($user, $date)
{
    return Task::where( 'user_id', $user->id )
                    ->where('date', $day)
                    ->with('job')
                    ->get();
```

App/Http/Controllers/PlannerController.php

```
public function index( Request $request )
    {
        return View::make( 'pages.planner.index' )
            ->with( 'task', Planner::getTask( 1, '2022-26-05' ) );
    }
```

and finally in resources/views/pages/planner/index.blade.php

```
<div>
   <div>{{ $task->job->title }}</div>
</div>
```

The task references the 'number' field in job via it's 'job_number' field and job doesn't contain any reference to task (as a job can have many tasks)

So how do I get the title of a tasks job without getting the N+1 error?

thanks

** EDIT **
Following suggestions by WebPajooh. I have modified the above code to remove the parenthesis in my blade file and removed all() from the relationship.

I still get a N+1 error:

> Found the following N+1 queries in this request:
>
> Model: App\Models\Task => Relation: App\Models\Job - You should add
> "with('App\Models\Job')" to eager-load this relation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following on from suggestions by WebPajooh I found that adding `protected $with = ['job'];`to my Task model allowed my code to work without this issue.

Answer (score 3):

When you write `job()`, it returns a relationship but when you write `job` without parentheses, it doesn't call the relationship.

Note: You don't need to call `all()` after `get()`, because `get()` returns a collection.

Comment: Please see above edits. Still get a N+1 error with suggested changes.